# How to only find values that appear across multiple tables in SQL

Tags: sql

I was hoping someone could help me with an issue I'm currently having in querying names that appear across multiple tables. For a bit of background, I'm using Microsoft Access to write my SQL query.

I have a source list of names that I would like to check if they appear across multiple tables in my database. For instance, the name on the source list should appear across all of the tables I am querying.

Currently I have the following code written, but it seems to provide an error that the results are too large. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
Select Key.UltimateParent
FROM ((((Key
LEFT JOIN MassPC on Key.UltimateParent = MassPC.UltimateRollup )
LEFT JOIN Maine on Key.UltimateParent = Maine.UltimateRollup)
LEFT JOIN NY on Key.UltimateParent = NY.UltimateRollup )
LEFT JOIN Texas on Key.UltimateParent = Texas.UltimateRollup)
LEFT JOIN Florida on Key.UltimateParent = Florida.UltimateRollup
where MassPC.UltimateRollup is not null and Maine.UltimateRollup is not null and NY.UltimateRollup is not null and Texas.UltimateRollup is not null and Florida.UltimateRollup is not null
Group by Key.ultimateparent
```

Comment: outer table.column is not null -> inner join...

Comment: Do a big union then `group by X having count (*) > 1` to find duplicates. Or `=50` if you want all tables.